# How to print a nested list like a grid?

Tags: python, nested-lists, python-3.10

```
l1 = [[" "], [" "], [" "], [" "], 
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "],
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "],
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "]]
```

As you can see I want these 16 empty "boxes"
To have an output of 4x4.
I tried to search Stack Overflow and the web for solutions to this. But nothing seems to work, as the questions regarding nested lists mostly have to do with integers.

Desired output:

```
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
```

Or:

```
[   ][   ][   ][   ]
[   ][   ][   ][   ]
[   ][   ][   ][   ]
[   ][   ][   ][   ]
```

Comment: Could you provide a desired output example?

Comment: I seem to be unable to edit my question. But the desired output would be similiar to I have chose to structured my list
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]
[" "][" "][" "][" "]. 

EDIT: appearntly, you can not format in the comment section

Comment: if you know the original size you can use nested fors to print this:
for i in range(4):

Comment: I will have to reuse my list for my TicTacToe game. 
That is why I need to iterate over my current list and not simply to make an iteration that generates a 4x4 brackets

Comment: But I will try to use it. See if it works

Answer (score 0):

if you know the original size you can use nested fors to print this

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        print(l1 [ i*4 + j] ,end='')
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

##### code

```
l1 = [[" "], [" "], [" "], [" "], 
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "],
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "],
      [" "], [" "], [" "], [" "]]

for i, e in enumerate(l1):
    if (i+1)%4 != 0:
        print(e, end='')  # print box without new line
    else:
        print(e)
```

##### Output

```
[' '][' '][' '][' ']
[' '][' '][' '][' ']
[' '][' '][' '][' ']
[' '][' '][' '][' ']
```

Comment: Omg thank you. This almost broke my brain from frustration. I will try to study your code and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I want to print out my 2d map in the console.

Here is what I did.

**Code**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  chunk = [
    ["61", "61", "61", "61"], 
    ["61", "61", "61", "61"], 
    ["61", "61", "61", "61"], 
    ["61", "61", "61", "61"], 
  ]
  
  print(*chunk, sep="\n")
```

**Output**

```
['61', '61', '61', '61']
['61', '61', '61', '61']
['61', '61', '61', '61']
['61', '61', '61', '61']
```